# Server side javascript/java - javascript communication

Tags: javascript, java, server, client

A) Are there any resources of how to use server-side javascript without Node.js?

B) Can a java-based server communicate with a javascript-based client?

Both options are okay (I would be more happy with the B though).

My goal is a simple client-server communication, and I think, that websocket still doesn't stand on two legs.

I appreciate your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably **the best part of the REST services that they are language-agnostic**. You can write serverside REST services in any language you want, then consume them from a completely different language. The most basic example (what you mentioned in option B) is combining Java and JavaScript. There are plenty of tutorials showing how to do that, maybe this one:

[JAX-RS + JQuery](http://coenraets.org/blog/2011/12/restful-services-with-jquery-and-java-using-jax-rs-and-jersey/)

is the best as a starter, because it highlights the important part. Later on you may want to go for some more advanced JS library to produce production-ready code faster.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that.

Comment: Ha, just noticed you're hungarian too.

Comment: Yepp. I would not have guessed from your name though... :)

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to change this one

Answer (score 0):

B is definitely possibly with Jersey JAX-RS and JSON encoded responses.  It can automatically parse incoming JSON-formatted query (typically GET/PUT/DELETE) params or body (typically POST) parameters into POJOs and can transform returned POJOs into JSON for the response.

More than possible we do it in production with a Marionette.js and Backbone.js based front-end.

WebSocket requires a bit of custom protocol work on your part and loses caching and other client optimizations.  It is s best suited to realtime message-oriented or incremental binary upload/download workloads.